# Disable automatic download of APK expansion files

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

Is it possible to disable the automatic download of the APK expansion file when you download the application from google play?

Can I force google play to disable the download and let the application download itself the expansion file?

Thanks

Comment: I know you should process downloading it yourself if downloading by play store fails for sure, I don't know however if it's possible to block automatic download... Hope someone wise answers :).

Comment: I don't think so. The expansion files are downloaded from Google Play's application automatically, and they've provided no control mechanism to modify this behavior. Is there a specific reason for you to wish for downloading the files yourself?

Answer (score 2):

If it's your own application you want to test, the best option is to install localy the .apk file on your device without the expansion pack. Upload the application and expansion pack to Google Play and activate it without publishing. When you first start your application, the expansion files will be downloaded from Google Play. This way you can test your expansion files downloader.

Answer (score 0):

@Kai
Is there a specific reason for you to wish for downloading the files yourself?
Yea, our App has many stages(game), each requires its own specific data(media), so downloading only the required data will help increase convenience of the user by avoiding unwanted paid mobile data usage...

Comment: Did you find a way to do this ? Please let me know